# Moka Express Pot, rusting?

Tags: moka

I know the Bialetti Moka pots are aluminium and I understood this means they can't rust? But mine seems to have a small spot of rust on the hinge part? Is this part not aluminium?

Is there anything I can do to this spot or does it matter?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/thD2rWl.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Aluminum is not a very strong metal when it comes to moving parts. Probably, that small rod that keeps the handle in place is made from steel to last longer. Rust may be formed because of steam or if you don't towel dry it after washing it. No worries as it is not in contact with your beverage. I can't check mine as it's not currently with me.